# Why does program miss 'if' operator?

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

The problem is the wrong executing of the program because of it misses condition statements in some function apparently.

Here is some example:

```cpp
void f(uint32_t eventsFlags) // eventFlags == 0x1
{
    // statement 1
    ...
    // statement N

    if (SOME_VAL_1 | eventsFlags) // SOME_VAL_1 == 0x1 (true)
    {
        // statement N+1
        ...
        // statement M
    }

    if (SOME_VAL_2 | eventsFlags) // SOME_VAL_2 == 0x40 (false)
    {
        // statement M+1
        ...
        // statement K
    }
}
```

When I debug it, 'statement N+1' comes right after 'statement N' missing the condition check between them. The same thing happens to 'statement M' and 'statement M+1' and the condition check between them. That is the reason of statements from M+1 to K are executed but they must not.

Edited: Excurse me as I have not noticed there is `|` instead `&` beacuse it really had been `&` until I inattentively had changed the code sometime.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by "missing the condition check"? If "statement N+1"  comes after "statement N" then it simply means that the condition was true.

Comment: Also remember that in C all non-zero values are true. And that you use bitwise OR operator and not the logical OR operator `||`. Or perhaps you meant to use bitwise AND `&`? `0x40 | 0x01` will be `0x41`, while `0x40 & 0x01` will be `0x00` (and zero is "false").

Comment: You're probably "debugging" using optimised code.   The optimiser is free to reorder operations, as long as the observable end effect (in terms of producing observable program output) is preserved.    It is not required to ensure that the flow of execution when stepping through with a debugger is the same as you expect by looking at the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x40` will be evaluated to true, as will any integer that is not zero. Since `0x40 | x` will always have at least one bit set to 1 for any `x` it will never become 0, thus this expression will always be evaluated to `true`. Same goes for `0x1`.

Probably you want to use `&` to check if the flag contains a specific value:

```
if (SOME_VAL_1 & eventsFlags) {...}
if (SOME_VAL_2 & eventsFlags) {...}
```

Comment: @walnut `0x40 | x` will always have one bit set, since `0x40` has one bit set.   Which means it is non-zero.

Comment: @walnut That's what I meant, but you are correct that it can be easily misunderstood the way I wrote it :)

Comment: @Peter Yes, sure. I was just worried that the old wording of the question (now improved) didn't make that clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

The condition you are checking is always true. There is no value for `eventsFlags` that makes it false since `SOME_VAL_1` is always non-zero.

If `a` and `b` are integers, `(a | b)` is only false if both `a` and `b` are zero.

Comment: Ah yes, seems OP wanted `&`, not `|`. And since the always-true condition is compiled out, OP also won't observe it being executed in the debugger.